# Is there a way to programatically determine whether JMeter is being run in 'functional test mode'?

Tags: jmeter

I've been given the task of implementing a set of JMeter tests that can be used for either performance or functional testing of a REST api. To do this, I want to be able to skip error case requests and heavier weight assertions during a performance test to keep the simulated traffic realistic and the overhead on the machine running the test low. 
Right now I'm determining whether the tests are executed as a performance test via a User Defined Variable. If it's value is 'true' some requests and assertions are skipped. Flow is controlled via JSR223 scripts in Groovy.
The solution works just fine, but having that UDV annoys me when JMeter already has a checkbox for 'Functional Test Mode'. I have searched to no avail for a way to programatically check the state of that checkbox. Is there a way I am missing, or am I stuck with a semi-redundant UDV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, given you already use JSR223 and Groovy you can obtain the `Functional Test Mode` setting from the [TestPlan class](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/testelement/TestPlan.html#isFunctionalMode--) as follows:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.SearchByClass

import java.lang.reflect.Field

StandardJMeterEngine engine = ctx.getEngine()
Field test = engine.getClass().getDeclaredField("test")
test.setAccessible(true)
HashTree testPlanTree = (HashTree) test.get(engine)

SearchByClass<TestPlan> testPlanSearch = new SearchByClass<>(TestPlan.class)
testPlanTree.traverse(testPlanSearch)
Collection<TestPlan> testPlans = testPlanSearch.getSearchResults()
TestPlan testPlan = testPlans[0]

log.info('Functional test mode: ' + testPlan.isFunctionalMode())
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Functional Testing Mode Obtaining]

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) for more examples on how Groovy can be used in JMeter scripts.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri, that worked for me. Thanks for the pointer to the cheat sheet as well. Sorry for the slow response, I had a fire to put out on another project.