# How to get body data request in jmeter using java

Tags: java, jmeter

I want to create plugin jmeter and i want to get body data request using java

[Image: Content i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcB8q.png)

In jmeter i using groovy to get

```
ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
```

or

```
Arguments argz = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getArguments();
for (int i = 0; i < argz.getArgumentCount(); i++) {
   Argument arg = argz.getArgument(i);
    String a = arg.getValue();
    vars.put("EMAIL",a);
 }
```

but in java i can't using function getArguments() in
 [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)

Answer (score 0):

`ctx` is a shorthand for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html) class you can access it from the Java Request sampler by calling [JMeterContextService.getContext() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html#getContext--).

Example usage:

given your [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) sampler is placed after the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler you can get its body like:

```
((org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy)org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getPreviousSampler()).getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
```

You can find an example of creating a Java Request sampler in the [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article.

Comment: Thank you. I can get body data request but it get after i running http request. I need get body data before http request running

Comment: Theoretically it is possible using [HashTreeTraverser](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jorphan/collections/HashTreeTraverser.html), you can find an example which assumes [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528586/is-there-a-way-to-programatically-determine-whether-jmeter-is-being-run-in-func/51531904#51531904), but you should be able to convert it to Java quickly and easily.

Comment: No. I want using java like PreProcessor in jmeter but using java to create plugin. Do you know example code?